# Linear application ${\Bbb R}^3\to {\Bbb R}^3$, $x\mapsto Ax$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have problem to understand what $x\to Ax$ means. For example if we have matrix $A$ and and linear application ${\Bbb R}^3\to {\Bbb R}^3$, $x\to Ax$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a map.

You can transform any data column
$\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{array}\right)$
by multiplication with a given matrix
$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{array}\right)$ in the order:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{array}\right),$$
to get an assigned triple:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
ax+by+cz\\
dx+ey+fz\\
gx+hy+iz\\
\end{array}\right).$$